# SQL count how many rows have the same value and do the sum on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

I have a question for you today. I have this table

| oddId | risk | resultCode | finalResult |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6.66667 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 7.14286 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 8.33333 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 8.33333 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 10 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 10 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 10 | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | 10 | 2 | 2 |
| 9 | 11.1111 | 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 11.1111 | 2 | 2 |
| 11 | 12.5 | 2 | 1 |
| 12 | 12.5 | 2 | 2 |
| 13 | 12.5 | 1 | 1 |
| 14 | 12.5 | 2 | 1 |
| 15 | 12.5 | 2 | 1 |
| 16 | 12.5 | 1 | 2 |
| 17 | 12.5 | 1 | 1 |
| 18 | 12.5 | 1 | 2 |
| 19 | 12.5 | 2 | 1 |
| 20 | 14.2857 | 2 | 2 |
| 21 | 14.2857 | 1 | 2 |
| 22 | 14.2857 | 2 | 2 |
| 23 | 16.6667 | 2 | 2 |
| 24 | 16.6667 | 1 | 2 |
| 25 | 16.6667 | 1 | 1 |

For this job I need

1. group the rows by "risk"
2. count how many rows have the same "risk" value
3. Count how many rows have the same value in "resultCode" and "finalResult"

---

With

```
SELECT  `risk`, `resultCode`, `finalResult`, 
        ( SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            FROM  matches
            WHERE  `resultCode` = t.`finalResult`
              AND  `oddId` = t.`oddId`
        ) equal
    FROM  matches t
    WHERE  `finalResult` IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY  `t`.`risk` ASC
```

i can get "equal" column.

| risk | resultCode | finalResult | equal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6.66667 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 7.14286 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 8.33333 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 8.33333 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 10 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 11.1111 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 11.1111 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 12.5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 12.5 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 12.5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 12.5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 12.5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 12.5 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 12.5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 12.5 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 12.5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 14.2857 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 14.2857 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 14.2857 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 16.6667 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 16.6667 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 16.6667 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

with

```
SELECT  `risk`, COUNT(`risk`) as total
    FROM  `matches`
    WHERE  `finalResult` IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY  `risk`
    ORDER BY  `risk` DESC
```

I can get "total" column.

---

Now I would also like to have a column where I group by "risk" and sum the "equal" columns (into "corrects"), to have...

| risk | corrects | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6.66667 | 0 | 1 |
| 7.14286 | 0 | 1 |
| 8.33333 | 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 | 4 |
| 11.1111 | 1 | 2 |
| 12.5 | 3 | 9 |
| 14.2857 | 2 | 3 |
| 16.6667 | 2 | 3 |

but *I don't know how to do*... Can anyone help me please? **Thank you very much**

MySQL - MyISAM - 5.6.48-88.0

Comment: Tag your specific database and state its version.

Comment: Done, MySQL 5.6.48-88.0

Comment: You should switch to InnoDB.  (No it won't address the question, but it is desirable for many other reasons.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sql is too confusing, so you don’t see the answer clearly

```sql
SELECT
    `risk`,
    COUNT( `risk` ) AS total,
    sum(case when resultCode = finalResult then 1 else 0 end) corrects
FROM
    `matches` 
WHERE
    `finalResult` IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY
    `risk` 
ORDER BY
    `risk` DESC
```